# Delete records from a collection of a specified DB

Tags: django, pymongo, mongoengine

I am using mongoDB as my database, i am working on django projects and using mongoengine to connect with database. My question is if my default database in `settings.py` is `DB1` and i want to delete **all records of a collection which exists inside `DB2`** then how can i do this.

**settings.py**

```
import mongoengine

mongoengine.connect(
    db= "DB1",
    host='localhost',
)
```

**models.py**

```
class Resources(Document):
    field1= fields.StringField(max_length=20)
    field2 = fields.StringField(max_length=70)
    field3 = fields.StringField(max_length=70)
    field4 = fields.DictField()

    meta = {'collection': 'resources', 'allow_inheritance': False, '_target_db': 'DB2'}
```

**python shell**

```
from .models import Resources
import mongoengine
mongoengine.connect('DB2', alias='ces')
ob = Resources()
ob.switch_db('ces')
ob.field1 = value
ob.field2 = value
ob.field3 = value
ob.save()
```

Now i have collection `resources` in `DB2` and it has some records, i have tried `Resources.objects.all().delete()` **but it is not deleting records form `DB2` instead it deletes records from `DB1` which is default database.**

Comment: Have you defined DB2 in settings.py file? This is happing because you have only DB1 defined in settings.py file, and all your actions to `Resources` will take place to DB1.

Comment: no i haven't, how to define `DB2` in `settings.py`?

Comment: Django natively dosen't support mongoDB, so you cant use the builtin django ORM. Are you using some third party library for the django mongodb integration?

Comment: In your case I guess you have model with the same name(Resources) in your Django models and when you Resources.objects.all().delete() you are actually calling the django model and not the mongoengine document. Can you show us the code where you are calling the delete() method?

Comment: yes i am using `djongo` to connect django with mongodb.

Comment: my `models.py` does not have model with same name `Resources`, i think to save data we have to use `switch_db` but to remove we are not using anything like `switch_db` to tell from which DB we want to delete collection.

Answer (score 0):

If each of your model is bound to 1 (and only 1) database, you can achieve what you want using connection `alias` and `meta = {'db_alias': 'your_connectio_alias'}` ([docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html#multiple-databases))

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56434241/6203472) for an example